# How to I declare to Ocean that my custom domain object can free memory?

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'd like to link my custom domain object into the Petrel free memory command. My domain object  caches data while visualised and this cache could be cleared when the user wants to free memory.

I have found the IMemorySaver interface and tried declaring this on my custom domain object but the FreeMemory method is not called when the user choose to free memory in Petrel.

Any ideas?

Neal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ocean 2013.1 a new API has been introduced that allows custom domain objects and ToggleWindows from a plug-in to be told  when the user has invoked the ‘Free memory’ feature (this will also work for programmatic calls to PetrelSystem.ForceFreeMemory()).

The API follows a similar pattern to the existing INameInfoFactory and IImageInfoFactory APIs.

In order to use the API you need to create a factory object for your custom domain object (or ToggleWindow) that implements the new IResourceSaverFactory interface.

This interface requires that you implement a single method called GetResourceSaver(). This 
method will return a ResourceSaver object that is associated with your custom domain object (or ToggleWindow).

ResourceSaver is an abstract class and you should implement the FreeResources() method on your derived class.

When the ‘Free memory’ feature is invoked the system will use your ResourceSaverFactory to obtain a ResourceSaver object for each of your custom domain object (or ToggleWindow) instances.

The FreeResources() method will be called on your ResouceSaver
objects.

Regards,

Chippy

Answer (score 0):

Neal, the IMemorySaver is declared as a service interface, which you should not re-implement.

Having said that, participation in Petrel's controlled resource management is a fair requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I'll submit a request via Ocean support for this feature.

Comment: This feature has already been implemented as explained in my answer previously - you should use IResourceSaverFactory/Source.